# Create a service that logs all input

Tags: linux, networking, services

I need to create a service that logs all input on a certain port to a file.  Do I have to create a custom program for this, or is there an already existing tool out there?

Comment: I have updated the question for RHEL base system, if you are using any other version let me know , I will update that also..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help of [IPtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) and [Syslog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) , we can logs all input on a certain port to a file.

IPtables default log file is `/var/log/messages` in RHEL based System and `/var/log/syslog` in Debian base system. we can log details to different log file.

Open your `/etc/syslog.conf` and Append following lines

```
kern.warning   /var/log/iptables.log
```

after adding , you have to restart syslog service to reflect changes using :

```
/etc/init.d/syslog restart
```

Now suppose you want to log port 80 , then just add below rule :

```
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-level 4
```

Now just tail the logs and see

```
tail -f /var/log/iptables.log
```

To save rule :

```
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

and enable required services at Start-up

```
chkconfig --level 35 iptables on
chkconfig --level 35 syslog on
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tools out there but one of the most common is [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/). It's almost undoubtedly available in your distribution's package repository or you could of course build it from source.

The daemon usually listens on port 514 UDP and accepts UDP packets which are then put into specific log files based on rulesets specified in your `rsyslog` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It think also [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) could be handy here. (It is not limited to TCP)